# Measure theory problem - Integrable functions- Showing f=0 a.e

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f \in L^1(R) $ and satisfies $\limsup_{h\to0}\int_R |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}| = 0$ then show that $f=0$ a.e.

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem ( I have a feeling that we need to use the dominated convergence theorem but no idea how to apply it) and what's the significance of almost everywhere in this question?

Comment: @LizardKing: $\int f= 0$ would not imply that $f = 0$ a.e. But $\int |f| = 0$ would imply that.

Comment: The result seems not true: if $f\in L^1$, the integral in the statement vanishes for every $h\neq 0$. Is there a modulus missing?

Comment: Yes a modulus sign is missing. Could explain how to do it with the modulus sign

Comment: I edited the question , Can you show how to approach it?

Comment: Even if modulus sign any non zero constant function is a counterexample

Comment: @Aditya Dwivedi but such a function wouldn't be $L^1$

Comment: @Gono Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true.
Consider $$f=1_{[0,1]} $$ the indicator function of the unit interval. Then we have for $0.1 > h>0$ that $$f(x+h)-f(x) = 1_{[-h,0)} - 1_{[1-h,1)} $$ and so we get $$\int_R f(x+h)-f(x) dx = h - h = 0$$
The same result we get for $-0.1 <h <0$ and so we get $$ \limsup_{h\to0}\int_R \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} dx =  \limsup_{h\to0}\frac {1}{h}\int_R f(x+h)-f(x)  dx = 0$$

Comment: Thank you yes a modulus sign is missing. Could you explain how to do it with the modulus sign?

Comment: I edited the question. Will you be able to show how to do it?